# Get float[] as FloatBuffer class

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, floatbuffer

Having a `float[]` and I want to put it as argument for `glLoadMatrixf(FloatBuffer m)` (interface of [GLMatrixFunc](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/jogl-2.x-docs/javax/media/opengl/fixedfunc/GLMatrixFunc.html)) .

How could I get the `float[]` as `FloatBuffer`  ?

The code is  -

```
float[] currentMatrix = {.....} ;
gl.glLoadMatrixd(currentMatrix );
```

The above prompts   - `The method glLoadMatrixf(FloatBuffer) in the type GL is not applicable for the arguments (float[])`

Comment: You might want to make sure that gl.glLoadMatrixd doesn't only accept DirectBuffers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float[] floatArray = ...;
FloatBuffer floatBuffer = FloatBuffer.wrap(floatArray);
```